# How can I make text align right of image?

Tags: css

I have a hyperlink that contains an image, nothing special - like this .

I want to align the text to the right of the image as per attachment1, but the result is as per attachment2. I need to also block the hyperlink so that it fills the rectangle (its width and height)

[image: Attachment1]

[image: Screenshots]

Anyone know how to acheive this?

Comment: You will probably need to set the width of the <a> so the link will wrap. Without the css or html it's hard to give a better answer. Also if your image and text is in the same <a> tag you should probably separate it for more control or add a div tag or something so you can target the text and set the width. Also may have to position absolutely the img and text or do something like inline-blocks. Hard to know without code.

Comment: @j08691 - there's not much html to view its simply an image inside an anchor

Comment: Have you tried floating the image?

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the answers. I chose the first answer to lead me to a solution, but thanks again to everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bunch of ways to do this:

Using `<div>`'s

```
<div style="width: 200px;">
<div style="float: left; width: 70px;">
<img src="http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/749158551/Ry_reasonably_small.jpg" width="64" height="64" />
</div>
<div style="float: right; width: 130px;">
<p><strong><a href="#">This is a really really over sized title for a link to neverland</a></strong></p><p>Some other text</p>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;">
</div>
```

Using a `<table>`

```
<table width="200">
  <tr>
   <td rowspan="2"><img src="http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/749158551/Ry_reasonably_small.jpg" width="64" height="64" /></td>
   <td><strong><a href="#">This is a really really over sized title for a link to neverland</a></strong></td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Some other text</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

put this on your page, see what is happening. Cheers

```
<div style="width:500px;height:250px; padding:10px; padding-left:250px; border:solid 1px black; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:left center; background-image:url('https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-v0soe-ievYE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAlUA/EHduo3GhTDs/s250-c-k/photo.jpg')">
        Google – 52 minutes ago – September 8 marks the anniversary of Star Trek's first broadcast, and naturally ... Amit Singhal originally shared this post: OK, I admit it, I am a die-hard Trekkie. I grew up watching endless ...
        Google – 18 hours ago – By now, you may know that when you search for [define] followed by a word, Google will show you the definition. But did you know that there's a Dictionary mode ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @njk, but using the `a` as the block element.
http://jsfiddle.net/scrimothy/r6TKz/